# Weird behavior in Django queryset union of values

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.10

I want to join the sum of related values from users with the users that do not have those values.

Here's a simplified version of my model structure:

```py
class Answer(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    # irrelevant model fields
```

Sample dataset:

```
Person | Answer.Points
------ | ------
3      | 50
3      | 100
2      | 100
2      | 90

Person 4 has no answers and therefore, points
```

With the query below, I can achieve the sum of points for each person:

```
people_with_points = Person.objects.\
        filter(answer__correct=True).\
        annotate(points=Sum('answer__points')).\
        values('pk', 'points')

<QuerySet [{'pk': 2, 'points': 190}, {'pk': 3, 'points': 150}]>
```

But, since some people might not have any related `Answer` entries, they will have 0 points and with the query below I use `Coalesce` to "fake" their points, like so:

```
people_without_points = Person.objects.\
        exclude(pk__in=people_with_points.values_list('pk')).\
        annotate(points=Coalesce(Sum('answer__points'), 0)).\
        values('pk', 'points')

<QuerySet [{'pk': 4, 'points': 0}]>
```

Both of these work as intended but I want to have them in the same queryset so I use the union operator `|` to join them:

```
everyone = people_with_points | people_without_points
```

**Now, for the problem**:

After this, the people without points have their `points` value turned into `None` instead of 0.

```
<QuerySet [{'pk': 2, 'points': 190}, {'pk': 3, 'points': 150}, {'pk': 4, 'points': None}]>
```

Anyone has any idea of why this happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should mention that I can fix that by annotating the queryset again and coalescing the null values to 0, like this:

```
everyone.\
    annotate(real_points=Concat(Coalesce(F('points'), 0), Value(''))).\
    values('pk', 'real_points')

<QuerySet [{'pk': 2, 'real_points': 190}, {'pk': 3, 'real_points': 150}, {'pk': 4, 'real_points': 0}]>
```

But I wish to understand why the union does not work as I expected in my original question.

EDIT:
I think I got it. A friend instructed me to use `django-debug-toolbar` to check my SQL queries to investigate further on this situation and I found out the following:

Since it's a union of two queries, the second query annotation is somehow not considered and the `COALESCE` to 0 is not used. By moving that to the first query it is propagated to the second query and I could achieve the expected result.

Basically, I changed the following:

```
# Moved the "Coalesce" to the initial query
people_with_points = Person.objects.\
    filter(answer__correct=True).\
    annotate(points=Coalesce(Sum('answer__points'), 0)).\
    values('pk', 'points')

# Second query does not have it anymore
people_without_points = Person.objects.\
    exclude(pk__in=people_with_points.values_list('pk')).\
    values('pk', 'points')

# We will have the values with 0 here!
everyone = people_with_points | people_without_points
```